# JMeter: How to detect the test has been cancelled in a JSR223 (Java) script

Tags: java, jmeter

I've written some Java code that runs in an endless loop.

How do I detect the test has been stopped, so I can exit the loop?

Answer (score 0):

There is [`running` property](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.3/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/threads/ThreadGroup.java#L82) in ThreadGroup class which is [being set to `false`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.3/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/threads/ThreadGroup.java#L392) when the test is stopping so you could check it somewhere in your loop like:

```
if (!ctx.getThreadGroup().running) {
    //do what you need here
}
```

Also be informed that if you choose `java` as the language in the JSR223 test element it's not real Java, it's [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) and [since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to use Groovy for scripting](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead/), moreover the above code won't even work and you will have to explicitly use [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) to read the `running` property value